# Tab Navigation Active JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have couple of tabs in my page like Features, Overview, Images etc. What i want to do is When there is no content in Features, I want to feature tab and content not to be shown in my page but only Overview and Images and the Overview should be the active one and content should be shown too. I manage to get the feature out but Overview does not become active. The only way it become active is when i click it. Also the contents for Overview is not shown and only can be seen when i click the Overview Tab. I am using JQuery to do this.

```js
//Remove tabs without content
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(0) p").length == 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(0).hide();
}
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(1) img").length == 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(1).hide();
}
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(2) tr.alt").length == 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(2).hide();
}
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(3) div.prod-table-thumbnail").length == 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(3).hide();
}
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(4) div.prod-table-thumbnail").length == 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(4).hide();
}
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(5) span.video-wrapper").length == 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(5).hide();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
$("ul.tabs li:first").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab-content-doc").hide(); //Hide all tab content
$(".tab-content-doc:first").show(); //Show first tab content
$("a.magnifying-glass.open-cbox").colorbox({opacity: '0.75', html: function () {
    var _html = document.createElement('div');
    _html.innerHTML = document.getElementById('prod-img-zoom').innerHTML;
    return _html;
}});
```

The above code is from xslt. The template file has this code. The code seems to have the logic to replace the first one to second one but its still not working.

```
//--Features
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(0) p").length == 0) {
    $("div.tab-content").eq(0).hide();
    $("div.tabs").eq(0).hide();
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(0).hide();
}
//--Overview
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(1) img").length != 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(1).show();
}
//--Images & Videos
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(2) div.tab-content-wrapper").length != 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(2).show();
}

var activeTab = defaultTab();

if(activeTab != null && activeTab != "" && activeTab != "undefined") {
    var index = activeTab.replace("tab","") - 1;  
    //Check if its valid tab to show
    if ($("ul.tabs li").eq(index).is(":visible")) {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive"); //Replace "active" class
        $("ul.tabs li:eq("+ index +")").removeClass("inactive").addClass("active"); //Replace "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab-content-doc").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        $(".tab-content-doc:eq("+ index +")").show(); //Show selected tab content
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use the `p`, `img`, `tr.alt`, ect tags or are you looking for tab content that is completely empty?

Comment: I didn't create this. I am trying to customize it and i don't have a good idea about it. What i want is when there is no content or completely empty then the tab and content should not be shown and also since its a first tab,it is the active tab so when there is no content then no tab and the active tab should be replace by second tab.

Comment: I posted an answer below.  Try that and see if it helps you.  It loops through your tab content and sees if there are any child elements of it.  If not, it will hide the tab associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are looking for `.tab-conent-doc` that is empty, correct?  If so, my suggestion would be to use jQuery's `children` function to see if each item is empty or not.

```
var $tabs = $('ul.tabs li'), //Get all tabs
    $tabContent = $('.tab-content-doc'), //Get all tab content
    idx; 
$tabContent.each(function(i) { //Loop through your tab-content-doc elements
    if($(this).children().length === 0) { //Are there children?
        $tabs.eq(i).hide(); //Hide the element that has no children
    }
});
idx = $tabs.filter(':visible').eq(0).index(); //What is the first visible tab?
$tabs.eq(idx)....//Do stuff with first visible tab
$tabContent.eq(idx)....//Do stuff with first visible tab content
```

Comment: Same result. It does hide the tab associated with the content. Since i am hiding the first tab, i want second tab with content to be active. The only way i can make active is to click on it.

Comment: @Gylabu Are you using jQuery UI tabs? Or some custom implementation?

Comment: $("ul.tabs li:first").show(); //Activate first tab
     $(".tab-content-doc").hide(); //Hide all tab content
     $(".tab-content-doc:first").show(); //Show first tab content
     $("a.magnifying-glass.open-cbox").colorbox({opacity: '0.75', html: function () {
      var _html = document.createElement('div');
      _html.innerHTML = document.getElementById('prod-img-zoom').innerHTML;
      return _html;
     }});

Comment: Hi Kyle, It seems a custom implementation.How do i know if its JQuery UI tabs? I don't see jquery-UI.js if thats what you are talking about then.

Comment: @Gyalbu Yes.  If you haven't included `jQuery UI`, then it would be a custom implementation.  I have posted an update.  That should help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer with me. What i did was before the remove tab without content code,there is a code which activates the first tab.

```
$("ul.tabs li:first").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab-content-doc").hide(); //Hide all tab content
$(".tab-content-doc:first").show(); //Show first tab content
```

I used if-else statement to show that if the first tab content is empty then go to second tab and make the second tab active. The code is:

```
if ($(".tab-content-doc:eq(0) p").length != 0) {
           $("ul.tabs li:eq(0)").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
           $(".tab-content-doc").hide(); //Hide all tab content
           $(".tab-content-doc:eq(0)").show(); //Show first tab content

      }
      else
      {
          $("ul.tabs li:eq(1)").addClass("active").show();//Activate second tab
          $(".tab-content-doc").hide(); //Hide all tab content
          $(".tab-content-doc:eq(1)").show(); //Show second tab content
      }
```

Thanks Kyle for helping me.